# How to use IF / THEN / ELSIF for Oracle Apex Page Validation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle 18c and Apex 19.1.  I'm trying to create a page validation process in APEX.  I have 4 Author fields each with a first name and last name for a total of 8 author-related fields.  I'd like to prevent the user from filling in only the last name, and leaving the first name blank.  I'm hoping I can put the validation of the four fields into one validation process.  I created the process as type **PL/SQL Function Body (returning Boolean)**.  I use the following code:

```
BEGIN
    IF       :P133_AUTHOR1_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR1_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author1 LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
             RETURN FALSE;
    ELSIF    :133_AUTHOR2_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR2_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author2LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
             RETURN FALSE;
    ELSIF    :133_AUTHOR3_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR3_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author3LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
             RETURN FALSE;
    ELSIF    :133_AUTHOR4_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR4_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author4LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
             RETURN FALSE;

    ELSE
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END;
```

It checks the first If/Then and shows the text in **Error Message** when appropriate.  However the code  ignores the remaining 3 ELSIF statements.  How do I construct the IF/Then/ElsIf statements so that it will RETURN FALSE when appropriate?

Comment: user3138025, is this still an issue? I see you were chatting with Littlefoot but then things went dead...

Answer (score 0):

Why reinventing the wheel? Set all those items to be **required**.

---

If you insist on your own validation, slightly rewrite it so that your code contains 4 separate `IF - END IF`s, i.e. (pseudocode)

```
if :author1_first is null or :author1_last is null then
   error
end if;

if :author2_first is null or :author2_last is null then
   error
end if;

etc.
```

---

How to collect all messages:

```
declare
  l_msg varchar2(500);
begin
    if :author1_first is null or :author1_last is null then
       l_msg := l_msg || 'First '; 
    end if;

    if :author2_first is null or :author2_last is null then
       l_msg := l_msg || 'Second ';
    end if;

    -- etc.

    l_msg := case when l_msg is not null then l_msg || ' author''s first and/or last name are missing';
                  else null
             end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Littlefoot.  I tried the method you mentioned above.  Same results.  It only looks at the first If/Then/End If and then ignores the rest of the code.

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, if the first does the `return`; it cancels execution of subsequent statements. If you want to collect **all** errors, then I suggest you create a local variable and concatenate all messages you want into it, and then - at the end - do the `return`.

Comment: Also, I tried the page item validation.  That won't work either.  If author1_Last contains "Shakespeare" and Author2_First is null, I'd like a validation error to appear.  However, if Author3_First and Author3_Last are both null, that's fine.  Don't show an error at all.

Comment: I tried it that way as well (leaving the returns out).  If I leave Author1_First blank, I get the proper validation error.  If I leave Author2_First blank, nothing happens.  The hidden error message page item (display-only while I debug this) doesn't get populated.  It seems that Apex PL/SQL Function Body Returning Boolean only processes one IF statement and then abandons the rest.  Hmmm.

Comment: Exactly, hmm. Looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a typo.  I was missing the "P" after the ":" on the ELSIF statements 2-4.  Once I fixed the typo's, it worked fine.
The corrected code is below.

```
BEGIN
    IF       :P133_AUTHOR1_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR1_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author1 LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
    END IF;
    IF       :P133_AUTHOR2_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR2_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author2 LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
    END IF;
    IF       :P133_AUTHOR3_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR3_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author3 LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
    END IF;
    IF       :P133_AUTHOR4_LAST_NAME is not null AND :P133_AUTHOR4_FIRST_NAME IS NULL 
    THEN
             :P133_AUTHOR_ERROR_MSG := 'Author4 LAST name is populated but the FIRST ' || 
             'name is blank.  Please populate both names for a given author.';
    END IF;

    If :P133_author_error_msg is null
    Then    
              Return TRUE;
    Else
              Return FALSE;
    End If;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a data problem.  I didn't notice it right away.  The code that I posted originally actually works fine.  Thanks for the responses.